# how to use Russian Language in HTML?

Tags: html, keyboard

how to use Russian Language in HTML? and Is their any best way to type in Russian Keyboard, if their is no option in PC? (Except Google) Actually Google translate my paragraph, but I need to add some text too.

Thanks

I tried using google translate.

Comment: Hi Muhammad. You have to learn YOUR keyboard. HTML is for ALL keyboards. So learn Russian keyboard and it will be good for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add russian as a new keyboard in [windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-the-input-and-display-language-settings-in-windows-12a10cb4-8626-9b77-0ccb-5013e0c7c7a2#WindowsVersion=Windows_11) . You can alter between your keyboards with ctrl + shift.

Answer (score 0):

For Que 1 - Try This

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru" xml:lang="ru">...</html>`

For Que 2 - I prefer Online Keyboard than installing in PC

[Online Russian Keyboard](https://www.typingkeyboard.com/russian-keyboard/)

Comment: You only have to enter the `lang="ru"` part. Everything else is very depending on situation.